# All statistics are 0

Tags: bug, status-completed

All of the statistic figures are at 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a problem with the API -- the stats will all be zero if that flair can't contact the API for any reason.

The flair refreshes itself every 10 minutes, so this has persisted for a while..

edit: was a combination of startup timing and incorrect sliding caching of this flair. Now fixed.